# Updating shadow variables of multiple chains

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to solve a cooperative team orienteering problem and thus implementing an Auto-Delay. I use shadow variables to store arrival and starting time as explained in the documentation.

My chains are as follows :

Vehicule 1 : [Vehicule1, TaskA(1/3), TaskB(2/3),...]     Arrival on A : 10, Start of A : 20

Vehicule 2 : [Vehicule2, TaskA(2/3),TaskB(1/3),...]      Arrival on A : 20, Start of A : 20

Vehicule 3 : [Vehicule3, TaskB(3/3),...]

The fact that TaskA cannot be completed is punished in the score calculation.

Optaplanner is now adding TaskA(3/3) before TaskB(3/3). Its Arrival time is 30

I wish to change the starting time of TaskA(1/3) and TaskA(2/3) to 30. BUT i also want to change the consequent arrival and starting time of TaskB(1/3) and TaskB(2/3) and tasks that are placed after.

TaskB(3/3) is in the source chain so it will be taken care of normally.

Ending time is based only on starting time in my problem.

What is the best way to do that ?